# Following a link into a git-repo without lengthy dialog

Tags: git, emacs, symlink

In a directory I have symbolic links into a git-administered directory (all under Linux). Every time I want to <kbd>e</kbd>-dit such a link I get a dialog question:

> `Symbolic link to Git-controlled source file; follow link? (yes or no)`

And I have to type <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>⏎</kbd> to get to the file. Is there a somewhat simpler way?

Ideally, something like declaring that a directory needs no dialog.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set `vc-follow-symlinks`.  You probably want it to be `nil` (open link), but be sure to read the docs because `t` (open target) is also sensible.

```
(setq vc-follow-symlinks nil)
```

You can make this a dir local variable if you don't want it set globally.

Comment: From the docs: "If this variable is t, VC follows the link and visits the real file, telling you about it in the echo area.  If it is ‘ask’, VC asks for confirmation whether it should follow the link.  If nil, the link is visited and a warning displayed."

So `nil` is essentially as if you answered "no" to the original question, and `t` is as if you answered "yes" to the original question. The `t` behavior seems more natural to me. I'm curious where `nil` would be preferable since I can't immediately think of such a case.

Comment: The doc for that variable says "Editing such a file through the link bypasses the version control system, which is dangerous and probably not what you want." I don't understand this. How does it bypass the VCS? and why is it dangerous?

Comment: @user98761 I'm not entirely sure how it's dangerous.  See this answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5831/651.  It seems to be about the "environment" of the buffer, e.g. default-directory.  Also I assume it's specifically about Emacs's internal vc package, so it might not apply if you use magit instead.

Comment: Ohh, I see. When they say "the version control system" here they mean VC itself, rather than the underlying actual VCS, e.g., Git. That makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

An interesting question. I store all my dotfiles in the repository and
have a bunch of symlinks scattered all over the filesystem so this is
a known problem to me.

First, a half-solution:

```
(defalias 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)
```

Now instead of typing a full `yes` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> you can just
type a single <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>n</kbd> letter in all situations
where `yes-or-no` is asked in `Emacs`.

Now, a real solution:

```
(defun vc-mode-hook ()
  (message buffer-file-name)
  (when
      (and
       (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name))
       (stringp buffer-file-name)
       (or (string-equal "/home/ja/.fluxbox/keys" buffer-file-name)
       (string-equal "<PATH_TO_ANOTHER_FILE>" buffer-file-name))
       (setq-local vc-follow-symlinks t)
       )))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'vc-mode-hook)
```

Here we create a new hook that is called every time `find-file` is
called, for example with <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>
<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>e</kbd> in `Dired`. It first checks
if a visited file really exists on the filesystem using
`file-exists-p` because it doesn't make sense to run it on files that
haven't been created yet. Next it checks if a file name is known using
`stringp` - it will return `t` when a regular file is opened but `nil`
in a `Dired` buffer for example. And finally it checks if the file
name is equal to one of strings provided using `string-equal`. If it
is, it locally sets `vc-follow-symlinks` to `t`. You can add as many
`string-equal` lines as you wish. In the example above I added
`/home/ja/.fluxbox/keys` and an placeholder for an another file name
in the next line.